# Create a curve that pass through 3 points

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have 3 points in space, $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Suppose there is a segment between $A$ and $B$ and in the middle of this segment, there is a perpendicular line where C is, just like that:

[image]

What I want is basically to create a function $curve(t)$ that represents the green curve, that is:

- $curve(0) = A$
- $curve(0.5) = C$
- $curve(1) = B$

and the other $t$ values represent points of the curve in the space.

How can I build such function?

---

If $A$ and $B$ were at the same height, I was using $curve(t) = ( A.x + t * (B.x - A.x),\; A.x + h * sin\left(t * \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right),\; A.z + t * (B.z - A.z))$

But this constraint doesn't exist so I don't know how to do yet.

Comment: For three points, as you know, we can trace a circle or a parabola for example.

Comment: You can parametrize the line segment $AB$ with the same $x(t)$, then combine it with your simplified version

Comment: What kind of curve are you looking for?

Comment: It can be a sin curve, any curve that fit A, B and C is ok.

Comment: Maybe NURBS is what you are looking for: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NURBSCurve.html or a Bezier Curve: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezierCurve.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let consider for $t\in[0,1]$, then

- $A+t(B-A)$ is the line from $A$ to $B$

the mid point $M$ between $A$ and $B$ is

- $M= \frac{A+B}2$

finally we need to add a term to reach $C$, that is for example

$$\operatorname{curve}(t)=A+t(B-A)+4t(t-1)(C-M)$$

with

- $\operatorname{curve}(0)=A$
- $\operatorname{curve}(1/2)=C$
- $\operatorname{curve}(1)=B$